# Operador ternário em PHP dá resultado inesperado

Tags: php, operadores

Recentemente fiz um teste e havia uma questão perguntando qual o retorno da expressão:

```
$var = true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3'
```

Respondi que o resultado seria '1', porém o resultado correto é '2'.
Se o código for escrito:

```
$var = true ? '1' : (false ? '2' : '3')
```

Ele irá retornar '1'.

Qual o motivo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto é um problema de [associatividade, e "por tabela", de precedência](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Toda linguagem bem pensada e bem feita tem esse operador com a associatividade da direita para esquerda. Isto faz muito mais sentido nesse tipo de operador, mas PHP obviamente escolheu o caminho errado, como tantas outras coisas, e usa a associatividade da esquerda para a direita. Junte-se ao fato dela ser uma linguagem de tipagem fraca e interpretar um tipo como se fosse outra, está aramada a confusão Então vamos colocar parênteses no código para ficar mais fácil de entender o que ele faz, lembrando que o operador por completo que estiver mais a esquerda é uma operação só:

```
(true ? '1' : false) ? '2' : '3'
```

Qual o resultado da expressão entre parênteses (obviamente a primeira a ser executada? Se é verdadeiro é claro que o resultado é `'1'`. Até aí fácil. Agora que sabemos este resultado vamos reescrever a expressão com o resultado:

```
'1' ? '2' : '3'
```

`'1'` é verdadeiro ou falso? Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) ele é considerado verdadeiro pelo PHP, qualquer valor que seja `false`, 0, 0.0, "0", *array* ou `SimpleXML` (não me pergunta porque só tem esta exceção) de zero elementos, ou NULL, é falso, o resto é verdadeiro.

Portanto sendo verdadeiro o resultado é `'2'`.

O segundo você está mudando a precedência com os parênteses explícitos, presumivelmente, onde deseja. A primeira expressão está isolada e pela condição já ser verdadeira já cai no primeiro operando depois da condição, o operando de falso nunca é executado neste caso, ele nem avalia a expressão que está entre parênteses.

De qualquer forma em qualquer linguagem de programação deve-se evitar aninhar operadores condicionais (não os chame de ternários porque um dia pode ter outro ternário que não seja esse condicional, ser ternário é outro nível de classificação do que ele é). Se for aninhar prefira ser mais legível colocando parênteses explícitos no que deseja. Isso vale para qualquer operador que não tenha precedência tão óbvia assim (ou seja, todos os que não sejam aritméticos, e provavelmente relacionais também são bem tranquilos, pra quem é experiente pode arriscar nos lógicos).

```
echo true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
echo "\n";
echo true ? '1' : (false ? '2' : '3');
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oEj7h9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rdocfecl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ConditionalPrecedence.php).